# Convert items in python list to paths

Tags: python, list

I have a python list which I need to make changes to the items
Here's my code till now

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path.cwd()
MAIN_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'Files'

mylist = ['6', '112318', '112319']

# outputlist = ['C:\\Users\\Future\\Desktop\\Files\\112318.pdf', 'C:\\Users\\Future\\Desktop\\Files\\112319.pdf']
```

So the first item is to be skipped and the other items to be converted to be as paths for pdf files in `Files` directory.

@Daweo
This is my attempt (can you please have a look and give me your review)

```
mylist = ['1', '112238', '112239', '112240', '112337', '165222', '112338']
files_list = [MAIN_DIR / f'{i}.pdf' for i in mylist[1:]]

final_list = []
final_list.append(mylist[0])

for file in files_list:
    if file.exists():
        final_list.append(file)       
    else:
        print(f'{file} ---> NOT Exists')  

print('=' * 50)
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it following way
from pathlib import Path

```
MAIN_DIR = Path("C:\\Users\\Future\\Desktop\\Files")
mylist = ['6', '112318', '112319']
outputlist = [MAIN_DIR / f'{i}.pdf' for i in mylist[1:]]
print(outputlist)
```

Output

```
[WindowsPath('C:/Users/Future/Desktop/Files/112318.pdf'), WindowsPath('C:/Users/Future/Desktop/Files/112319.pdf')]
```

Note: for sake of example simplicity I elected to use fixed `MAIN_DIR`. Features used: list slicing (to skip 1st element), f-string (for string formating, requires `python3.6` or newer), list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to check if each element (the path to file) exists or not? if not exists then print a message and removes it from the python list

Comment: I could loop to check if the file exists `for file in files_list:
    if file.is_file():
        print(f'The file {file} exists')
    else:
        print(f'The file {file} does not exist')` but how to remove the file if not exists?

Comment: @YasserKhalil you might use second list comprehension, with condition, i.e. add immediately before line with `print` in my code following line `outputlist = [i for i in outputlist if i.exists()]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can I print if the file doesn't exist? I think I have to loop

Comment: Inside the loop, I tried `files_list.remove(file)` but seems not to be working well.

Comment: I have updated the question to put the final attempt. Waiting for your review.

Comment: How can I get the string from the WindowsPath?

Comment: @YasserKhalil use `str` in above example `str(MAIN_DIR)`  will give `'C:\\Users\\Future\\Desktop\\Files'`